# Residents vs citizens to mean Chinese locals?

Tags: word-usage, word-choice, difference

I learned that residents differ from citizens [in the U.S.A.](https://blog.myrawealth.com/insights/citizen-vs-permanent-resident#:%7E:text=Not%20exactly.%20U.S.%20Citizens%20are%20people%20who%20legally%20belong%20to%20the%20country%20and%20truly%20are%20people%20who%20live%20in%20and%20identify%20as%20Americans.%20Residents%20are%20people%20who%20legally%20live%20and%20work%20in%20the%20country%20but%20do%20not%20have%20the%20same%20rights%20as%20citizens.) and some other countries,

> Not exactly. U.S. Citizens are people who legally belong to the country and truly are people who live in and identify as Americans. Residents are people who legally live and work in the country but do not have the same rights as citizens.

but I wonder if that also applies to China, considering that in China all Chinese are only permanent residents as described in Chinese ID card as depicted below.

[image]

I found that in [this academic paper](https://www.sciencedirect.com/topics/social-sciences/chinese-resident) the term "Chinese residents" is used to refer to Chinese. I wonder which of these would be appropriate in this scenario: nationals, locals, Chinese with nationality? Or there is a more canonical/official term to separate what we usually mean Chinese from other people?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because this is not about learning English, but about a specific piece of Chinese Law,  The cards are written in Chinese and don't contain any English text, in particular they don't contain the words "China Domicile"

Comment: @JamesK If there are English words on the card it becomes unnecessary for me to ask the question. I am asking for the alleged English words!

Comment: Well, "residents" is a perfectly good English word.  A resident of China would be someone living in China who may not be not a citizen of China.  That is a resident of China is someone who is domiciled in China, but is a citizen of a foreign country.  That is just the dictionary defintion

Comment: @JamesK I am confused. I think I made a mistake while using `domiciled`.

Comment: Domicile is a legal or tax word.  As a noun it mean "residence" (but not a temporary one). It is more often used as a verb (meaning to have a permanent residence) It is used for taxes, since you normally pay tax to the country in which you are domiciled, not where you are visiting, nor where you are from originally.

Comment: @JamesK So, which one of these is appropriate: nationals, Chinese with nationality, locals. Or others?

Comment: Can you edit your question to incorporate these comments?

Comment: @JamesK Is the current version appropriate?

Comment: You should ask on https://chinese.stackexchange.com/ They will be able to give an appropriate translation.

Comment: @StuartF When my expected answer is in Chinese I would ask on chinese.stackexchange.com.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several words here.

Firstly "Citizen" is a legally defined word.  Different countries define "citizen" in different ways.  In Chinese official translations it is used as a translation of 公民, and this word has a precise definition in Chinese law.

Then there is ethnicity. There are many ethnicities in China.  Han Chinese is the largest but there are many others.  An Englishman who has moved to China, renounced his British citizenship and taken Chinese citizenship is still ethnically English.  There are many native non-Han ethnicities in China:  Zhuang, Uyghur, Mongol, Tajik to name but a few.

And then "nationality". This is a complex issue.  It is used as a translation of " 国籍的" and Chinese constitution says "all Chinese nationals are Chinese Citizens", but the word in English is subtle and subject to political interpretation. Different people use the word "nationality" is subtly different ways, sometimes as synonym of "citizen", sometimes related to ethnicity, sometimes related to national identity.

And what about "residence". This is basically the answer to the  question, "Where do you live?"  This is your residence, or your domicile. Domicile is a more formal word with a specific definition in tax law.  These may be used to translate 居民.

But be aware that 公民, 国籍的 and 居民 may have a *legal definition in Chinese law* that differs from their use in everyday Chinese, and differs from the meaning of the English words in English law (or Scottish, or American etc)

So you might say "I live in China".  Great, so you are a resident of China.

Are you a citizen of China?  This is a legal status.

Are you a Chinese national?  This might mean different things to different people. But it could relate to your self-identity, or the identity that others put on you.

Are you ethnically Chinese? Or should I say "Are you Han Chinese?"?

There are people who live in China who are not citizens of China.  There are citizens of China who don't live in China. But most citizens of China are residents, and most residents of China are citizens.

Locals are just people who live nearby. This word has little to do with nationality.

Comment: Well,. the "official" terms are written in Chinese.  These are translations of the official terms, an hold no official status in China.  "凡具有中华人民共和国国籍的人都是中华人民共和国公民。"

Comment: So, the official terms are 'nationals' or 'citizens'. Thanks! I wonder if 'nationals' and 'citizens' are different because all citizens are not nationals as per [this Wiki page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wikipedia:Citizenship_and_nationality#:~:text=Nationality%20is%20obtained,by%20international%20law.).

Comment: Why should not the terms be called "official"? They are written on an official website.

Comment: They may be official translations, but the original and only authoritative version of the law is in Chinese.

Comment: In chinese **law**, all nationals of the PRC are citizens of the PRC.  And nationality here is defined **in law**  the meanings of the words in English and when not applied to in China are different, much wider and more flexible.

Comment: Okay I've done a big rewrite and reorder

Comment: Resident generally has specific legal meanings (hence off-topic here). It's not necessarily where you live, and there may be further legal tests. For example if you 'live in Bali', but don't have a residence permit, then you are arguably not a resident. In Indonesia you are legally 'resident' as long as you have a 'residence permit', and that will qualify you for naturalization. For the UK that's not enough, and if you have a residence visa but don't actually spend most of your time in the UK then they consider you NOT to be resident in the UK.